# Removing characters from NSArray stored on database

Tags: php, mysql, nsarray

Iv got some coordinates in an NSArray, Im storing them in a MySQL database with PHP and when retrieving them, they appear as this:

```
(
    "37.351701,-122.105898",
    "37.351945,-122.106109",
    "37.352183,-122.106338"
)
```

I need them to be:

```
37.351701,-122.105898,
37.351945,-122.106109,
37.352183,-122.106338
```

How can I remove the characters I don't need?

Creating the array:

```
self.trackCoord = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f",newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude];

        if (!self.trackArray) {
        self.trackArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        }
        [self.trackArray addObject:self.trackCoord];
        NSLog(@"%@", self.trackArray);

        //some code to post to the php url
```

PHP code that adds to the database:

```
<?php
mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
@mysql_select_db($db) or die("Unable to find database");

$trackArray = $_GET["trackArray"];

$query = "INSERT INTO routes VALUES ('', '".mysql_real_escape_string($trackArray)."')";

mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error("error"));
mysql_clsoe();
?>
```

Retrieving the array:

```
//some code to get the route
NSString* route = _currentRoute.trackArray;
NSArray* routeCoord = [route componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
NSLog(@"%@",routeCoord);
```

Comment: can you show the code of how you are storing them in your database?

Comment: @MichaelDautermann updated the question with the code

Answer (score 1):

Ah, now that I see what you're doing… you are actually doing everything correctly.

What is happening is that when you do this:

```
NSLog(@"%@",routeCoord);
```

you are printing out the enumerated contents of the array, which are NSString objects.

And as a convenience to display the contents of the directory, the "`description`" method of NSArray (which NSLog uses to print) puts the strings (`XXX,XXX`) into quotes by default.

The string containing the raw coordinates -- plus the comma between them -- and ***not*** the quotes, are what's being saved in your database.

Comment: Im looking into phpmyadmin, and all the coordinates I add look like this, just copied '(
    "37.335151,-122.032553",
    "37.335121,-122.032562",
    "37.335072,-122.032604"
    )'